# How to download additional files from modules on pycharm

Tags: python, module, pycharm

[This is the package I wanted to download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgVi6.png)

So I ran the command as shown in the picture and successfully downloaded it. However, how do I use this in pycharm.. I only use pycharm to code and pycharm does not recognise the file. The terminal however said

```
You can now load the model via spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
```

And this is where I think the file was downloaded

```
/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages
```

[Maybe it's something to do with my project interpreters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgjDO.png)

Comment: check in documentation if you can run some function directly in python code to download it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Python code

```
import spacy 

spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_sm")

#nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

It works for me.

---

I found it in [source code](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/cli/download.py)