# Spacy 2.0 Language Model load issues - from 'en_code_web_sm' to 'en_code_web_lg'

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

When I run the following code using **en_code_web_sm**

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)
```

but now when I change the language model to **en_code_web_lg**, I will have the following error:

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
doc = nlp("Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56470403/spacy-nlp-spacy-loaden-core-web-lg or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334304/spacy-cant-find-model-en-core-web-sm-on-windows-10-and-python-3-5-3-anacon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you downloaded the model `'en_core_web_lg'` to disk?

You can do this by running this in the command line:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

or in the script:

```
import spacy
spacy.cli.download('en_core_web_lg')
```

Comment: It works when I use the script. I understand why the question 'Are you sure you download the model...'. It took a long while to load the library, and use it to as well for a small sample.